# App crashes while opening Activity

Tags: java, android

Hello there fellows programmers! 
At the very start i must say that i'm learning android for 3 days now, so it might be some dumb probblem but I count on your understanding.
I'm trying to make a simple Activity which will be kind of DiceRoller. It worked for some time but then suddenly it started to crash when i'm even entering the Activity. I cannot understand the error - that's why i'm bothering you.

My XML code:
http://www.wklej.org/id/3118631/

Java code:
http://www.wklej.org/id/3118642/

Had to cut codes from my post cause of character limits.

Error log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.daniel.scrolltest3, PID: 24821
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.daniel.scrolltest3/com.example.daniel.scrolltest3.Dices}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #128: Binary XML file line #128: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #128: Binary XML file line #128: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:401)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2171)
        at com.example.daniel.scrolltest3.Dices.onCreate(Dices.java:76)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #128: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:401) 
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2171) 
        at com.example.daniel.scrolltest3.Dices.onCreate(Dices.java:76) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:401) 
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2171) 
        at com.example.daniel.scrolltest3.Dices.onCreate(Dices.java:76) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620) 
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 11520012 byte allocation with 7105080 free bytes and 6MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2738)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2643)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:152)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:140)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:136)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:401) 
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2171) 
        at com.example.daniel.scrolltest3.Dices.onCreate(Dices.java:76) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

Just while learning what is Glide by the suggestion of farhan patel in comments below, i've found a solution that works right now which was adding

android:largeHeap="true"

into my Manifest file. It looks like this right now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.daniel.scrolltest3">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".StartupMenu"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Karta1"/>
        <activity android:name=".MainMenu"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name=".Dices"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name=".ListaKart"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name=".Karta1_2" />
        <activity android:name=".WebPage"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you set the main activity class in your manifest file?

Comment: You are getting an OOM.What is your drawable size? try inflating them with Glide dynamically

Comment: My manifest file looks like this: http://wklej.org/id/3118653/

Comment: Few apps should be using `android:largeHeap="true"`. First, that will not solve your problem on many devices. Second, even if it does, you are using more system RAM than is necessary. 11520012 bytes is equivalent to a 1697 x 1697 pixel image, and that is **much too large**.

Answer (score 0):

First, do not use `fill_parent` use `match_parent`. **fill_parent** renamed as **match_parent** about 7 years ago. They do the same thing but **fill_parent** name is deprecated.

In my opinion, you are getting this error because you put all your images into **drawable** folder. And this behaviour, makes your device rescale your images and this causes `OutOfMemory` error in images with big resolution.

You need to resize all your images according to screen `DPI` and put them into drawable folders like below:

- drawable-xxxhdpi
- drawable-xxhdpi
- drawable-xhdpi
- drawable-hdpi
- drawable-mdpi

Check [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and [this](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html) for additional info.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! :) 
I will definitelly make a usage of it.